# Changing PATH for npm node_modules

Tags: npm, gulp, environment-variables, node-modules, git-bash

I've been troubleshooting problems with using npm packages for about 2 weeks now. Any node modules (I've tried gulp, gulp-cli, mocha, react, babel, and others) return a "command not found" error in Git Bash.

I have Windows 7 Professional, Node 8.11.1 (64-bit), npm 5.6.0.

What I have tried already is:

In the case of gulp-cli for Lecture 11 of [this course](https://www.udemy.com/git-a-web-developer-job-mastering-the-modern-workflow/learn/v4/content)

-- Uninstalling the package globally and reinstalling globally

-- Uninstalling and re-installing Node and npm completely

-- Changing the PATH and NODE_PATH of the Environment Variables

**User variables**

PATH:`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules\;C:\Users\Millionaire\AppData\Roaming\npm;`

**System variables**

PATH: `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules\;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm;`

**$ which node**

```
/c/Program Files/nodejs/node
```

**$which npm**

```
/c/Program Files/nodejs/npm
```

**$ npm list -g**

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local
```

Any help you can offer is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few times to do

```
$npm list-g {package name}
```

for gulp and http-server and others and it kept giving me

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local
```

So I added that to the system PATH environment variable. Exited and restarted Git Bash and it finally worked for me. Hallelujah.